# Why doesn't better_errors work on cloud 9 ide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide, better-errors-gem

I'm working on a number of projects on cloud9 IDE, and it's really frustrating that I can't get the better errors gem to work correctly. It isn't supposed to need initializing; it should just work out of the box. However, I still only get the usual ugly red errors page. I should specify that it is included in my gemfile, and I have `bundle install` already.

How can I get better errors to work correctly? Is there an installation step I'm missing?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick, I used, to get the 'better_errors' gem working in Cloud9 is setting the value of `TRUSTED_IP` to the public IP address of the computer my browser session is attached to. (As far as I can tell, it has nothing to do with the IP address of the remote server or Cloud9 server addresses.)

I'll outline the process I used to get 'better_errors' working on my Cloud9 workspace, from my Chromebook on my residential network... maybe it will also work for you and others!

1. Add `gem "better_errors"` to the development group in the project Gemfile.
2. Add `gem "binding_of_caller"` to the project Gemfile.
3. Run $`bundle` in the project Cloud9 terminal.
4. Edit the project **config/environments/development.rb** file and add the following line of code to the end of the **Rails.application.configure** block.

   ```
   BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! ENV['TRUSTED_IP'] if ENV['TRUSTED_IP']
   ```
5. Create a new "runner" in Cloud9 by clicking **"Run"** > **"Run With"** > **"New Runner"**.
6. Cloud9 creates an basic runner file in a new tab to modify. Replace the contents of this file with following code.

   ```
   {
      "cmd": [
        "bash",
        "--login",
        "-c",
        "TRUSTED_IP=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX rails server -p $port -b $ip $args"
     ],
     "working_dir": "$project_path",
     "info": "Your code is running at \\033[01;34m$url\\033[00m.\n\\033[01;31m",
     "selector": "source.ru"
   }
   ```
7. Replace `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` in the code above with the local computer's public IP address. (I use http://ifconfig.me/ to find the public IP assigned to my Chromebook.)
8. Save the runner file with the name **RoR.run** into the **/.c9/runners** path for the project.
9. Start the projects server by using this new runner. Click **Run** > **Run With** > **RoR**.
10. Use the popup link that Cloud9 displays, after the runner starts the server, to view the app. Enjoy 'better_errors'!

**NOTE:** I still have not figured out how to automate the process of feeding the external IP address of my local computer into the RoR.run file that lives on the Cloud9 workspace. I just update it manually every time I move to a new network or my external IP address changes.

**WARNING:** I actually just started learning RoR, so I have no idea if this is the "correct" way to get this gem to work in a cloud dev server/service environment. I also have no idea how safe this would be. I suspect that my solution exposes the 'better_errors' in-browser REPL to all computers that resolve to that same external IP address. If you are working on a sensitive codebase/database please do not implement my solution.

Comment: I also like to have the console display on routing error pages when I'm working on Cloud9. To do this I add   `config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = ENV['TRUSTED_IP']` to my projects **config/environments/development.rb** file.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this in cloud9.io and this is the simplest way to make this work in cloud9.io:

Add the following line to config/environments/development.rb:

```
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! 'xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24'
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx is the first three sections of the IP address of the *local* machine that you are using to connect to cloud9.io

Answer (score 2):

There is a good answer in the better errors issues and c0 docs.

Issues:
https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors/issues/318

c9 Help
https://community.c9.io/t/white-listing-remote-addr-for-better-errors-gem/4976/4

Use a `Rack::Request` object to get the IP. You can put the following code in your view.

```
   if Rails.env.development?
     request = Rack::Request.new(env)
     puts "@@@@@@ Request IP_ADDRESS = #{request.ip}"
   end
```

Change the last quadrant of the IP you get to `0/24`. For example.

```
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '76.168.69.0/24'     <--note: change the last quad to 0/24 and of course your ip address will be different than 76.168.69.xx
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah!! I got it! Automatically!
Here is my solution:

1- Similar as described by @Grokcodile: edit the project config/environments/development.rb file and add the following line of code to the Rails.application.configure block.

```
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! ENV['TRUSTED_IP'] if ENV['TRUSTED_IP']

config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = ENV['TRUSTED_IP']
```

2- At the Cloud9 edit the ~/.bashrc...

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

add the line (enter, alt+a):

```
export TRUSTED_IP='0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0'
```

Save it (esc, :wq)

3- run `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT` as usual...

4- **Enjoy better errors!!**

If you also work on this project at a Virtual Machine(vagrant):

1- edit at your VM (vagrant) your ~/.bash_profile (my case) and add:

```
export TRUSTED_IP=x.x.x.x
export PORT=3000
export IP=0.0.0.0
```

x.x.x.x must be equal to the REMOTE_ADDR of ENV. (This in not a problem like cloud9 because at my VM the IP doesn't change everytime: 10.0.2.2 always for me).

With this I am now able to use the gem foreman: `foreman start` at both places with the Procfile:

```
web: rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```

This works because the global env variables are set on both.

I am just starting to learn RoR too, so, hope this is the right thing to do without bringing more problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Because Cloud9 is all web-based you don't access it from localhost so by default better errors won't work. If you take a look at the security section of their README (https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) you can add the following to config/environments/development.rb:

```
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! <ipaddress>
```

So that the errors page shows for your IP. You can find your apparent IP by hitting the old error page's "Show env dump" and looking at "REMOTE_ADDR".

Comment: I added the line you mentioned above, and I replaced the `<ipaddress>` with a string containing my ip `"xx.xx.xx.xx"` and I got no change. Still showing the standard error page after I reboot the server.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. It might be worth sending an email to support@c9.io so they can diagnose why it's not working.